# can we use ngModel and ngChange in the same component

Tags: angular, angular9

```
arr= [{
    isNew: true,
    price: {
      perDay: 0,
      perMonth: 0,
      perHalfDay: 0
    },
    type: 3,
    available: false,
    newCapacity: 0,
    inventory: 1
  }...]
```

`<div *ngFor="let obj of arr">
    <input [(ngModel)]="obj.inventory">
</div>`

On change of a particular inventory I want to change its type/available field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngModelChange

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of arr">
    <input [(ngModel)]="obj.inventory" (ngModelChange)="yourFunction()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an ngModel and ngChange together. If you want to change the availability just changing the inventory you can use ngModelChange but If you want to submit the value of the input before change the availability of the product you must use `(change)="yourMethod()"`

Here I give you how works with your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6miryc